# 1. Using switches for multiple url variables

Tags: php

ok say i have these pages,

- /admin/admin.php
- /admin/blogger.php

inside my main index.php, i have a switch array that runs an 'if exists $page' function, which works fine. all my pages are called from site.com/index.php?page=about, site.com/index.php?page=misc, etc etc.

inside my admin.php page is a php tabbed navigation that uses 4 tabs for my admin sections (blogger/image manager/file manager/quotes manager). it uses a switch of tabfunctions for the 4 pages.

the blogger.php is where i have my switch in question.

now for my question:
instead of having multiple pages for the blog system, "delete.php, add.php, edit.php, etc" and using like 'to delete click (delete.php?id=1) here', i wanted to try and run it all from the blogger page. for example, "site.com/admin.php?page=blogger&act=dp/ep/ap" would get whichever $act is being passed and then using a switch to complete the action.

my PAGE switch works fine, but when i try to call more switches, it doesn't work. I tried using this as my code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {  
  $act = $_GET['act'];  
  switch ($act) {  
    case 'ap':  
      addPost();  
      break;  
    case 'ep':  
      editPost();  
      break;  
    case 'dp':  
      delPost();  
      break;  
    default:  
      ~table setup  
      ~$query, $result  
      ~if / while loops
      ~echo $row->article_id/title/author/date  
      echo "<a href=\"index.php?page=admin&amp;tabindex=0&amp;act=ep&amp;id={$row->article_id}\">Edit</a>"  
      ...  
      ...  
      ...
```

here is the issue i'm having. the page is correct, the tabindex is correct, then it stops working. i just get a blank page, not the edit page like i should. my editPost function is correct, as i've tested it from the editpost.php?id=1 way, which i am trying to avoid. and yes, my functions are included from here as well.

is the url not being passed right? or is my act switch not set up correctly. maybe setting an isset($_GET['act']) before the switch? i'm at a loss.

thank you.

Comment: are your errors visible?
Try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on start if they are hidden.

Comment: yes, for development purposes i have error_reporting(E_ALL); in my header.inc.php file.

Comment: I imagine this is all pseudo code what I see here, you are receiving act=del/edit/add from _GET, and there is actual case 'del/edit/add': break; section?

Comment: sorry i just corrected it in this post. add/edit/del should be ap/ep/dp to match my switch cases..  thanks for pointing that out to me. so yes, &act=ap/ep/dp switch is here.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try this after I'm back home where my dev files are and let ya know if it worked.

Comment: if you do it like that, user will be able to change order of actions and mess it up. it would make more sense (to me) that you differently organize your actions so for example if you would like to delete post whenever you add one, just run del() function before you create new one... stupid example, I know, but I hope you got my point?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pass multiple actions at once like this?

```
//test.php?action=add/update/notify
if(isset($_GET['action'])) {

  $act = $_GET['action'];

  //split actions
  $actions = explode('/', $_GET['action']);

  foreach( $actions as $action ){
      switch ($action) {  
        case 'add':  
          echo "add<br />\n";
          break;  
        case 'update':  
          echo "update<br />\n";
          break;  
        case 'notify':  
          echo "notify<br />\n";  
          break;  
        default:
        // default action if no match  (runs for every item of $actions array)
        break;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: // default action if no match  (runs for every item of $actions array) -------- does this mean if they use say $act=xDfklj43qrADF that it will display the default regardless of what they put not in my cases? or should i else the foreach?

Comment: you dont have to put anything in default, but in switch statement, whenever it`s run, default will be called if no match is found.

Comment: ok that's what i thought. but no, i didn't mean calling them all at once. not even sure how that would work. act=ap/ep/dp meant act=ap, or act=ep, or act=dp. sorry i should have specified more on that. i still am not having luck displaying the pages hence your first reply. i may have to clean up my site and see what extra misc stuff laying around may be causing it not to. tho i'd much rather have all my switches off a single page for the 2-4 variables that are passed. will try bobtheasian's idea see if that helps any.

Answer (score 0):

> site.com/admin.php?page=blogger&act=dp/ep/ap

You can't do that. Specifically `act=dp/ep/ap`. I would recommend a mix of `mod_rewrite` and multiple `$_GET` so then you could do like what WordPress does:

> site.com/admin/blog/edit

Mod_rewritten to:

> site.com/admin.php?page=blog&act=edit

From there you just have to use `$_GET` and have just one `switch` with dependencies.

```
 $page = $_GET['page']; 
 $action = $_GET['act'];

  switch ($page) {  
    case 'blog':  
          do($action);  
      break;  
    case 'news':  
          do($action);
      break;  
    case 'users':  
          do($action);
      break;  
    default: echo 'Try again.';
      break;
    }

    function do($act) {
     switch($act) {
       case 'delete': confirmDelete();
       break;
       case 'update': updateConfirm();
       break;
       }
    }
```

You get the idea.

Comment: I do like this idea, makes it cleaner and on a single page. I may have misread you, but I didn't mean act=dp/ep/ap, meant them as act=dp or act=ep or act=ap, just to clarify. but i do like this idea.. will toy around with it.. thanks for the idea

Comment: also i'm assuming without E_NOTICE I will get undefined errors on $page and $action if they aren't isset first, correct?